# RMM bypass - my Samsung Galaxy S7 does not show the developer options

Tags: bootloader-lock

I'm trying to access the developer options, while pressing 7 times on the build number, which triggers the reply "developer  mode has already been turned on", although I don't have these options anywhere below or above my "about phone". In a previous question a user here said that my problem was RMM related, which I'm not completely sure, but I'm willing to try to fix.

According to these guide: https://forum.xda-developers.com/samsung-a-series-2017/how-to/guide-root-install-twrp-samsung-t3747535 ; I need to flash latest full stock fw, and and wait 7 days, although since I'm from Portugal, I have a lot of options of firmaware as seen here: https://www.sammobile.com/samsung/galaxy-s7/firmware/SM-G930F/MEO/

Should I install the 30th of March version of 2020?

Comment: after tapping buildno 7x seven times try this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.androidstudio.developeroptions